# mark a string in one dataframe column if it's contained(substring) in another dataframe column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, substr, isin

I need to take df1 and check where 'Code' column values are contained (as substring)
in City column on df2, so that df1 would be rendered with an added new 'exists' column.

df1:
| name     | family-name    | Code|
| -------- | -------------- |-----|
| John     | heath          | don |
| Eric     | Miles          | ork |
| Duke     | Bravo          | brr |
| James    | Mac            | ris |
| Alec     | Blunt          | jjh |

df2:

| ID | City |
| --- | --- |
| 552 | Paris |
| 432 | London |
| 556 | New York |
| 457 | Rome |

output of new df1:

df1:

| name | family-name | Code | exists |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | heath | don | true |
| Eric | Miles | ork | true |
| Duke | Bravo | brr | false |
| James | Mac | ris | true |
| Alec | Blunt | jjh | false |

I tried this code but all values are false on the 'exists' column:
df1["exists"]= df1["Code"].isin(df2["City"])

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

While using the .isin you are trying to find only full matched strings, not substrings. From the .isin pandas documentation

```
The result will only be true at a location if all the labels match.
```

One solution would be to verify it char by char for every element, something like this

```
df1.Code.apply(lambda x: any(x in s for s in df2.City))
```